# How to mock database access with Moq while avoiding code smells?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

A bit of context: we use several databases, among which `DB_A` and `DB_B`. There is a table in `DB_B`, called `TableB`, whose data are based on those in table `TableA` from `DB_A`.

Class `MaintainDB_B` has a method `MaintainTableB()` that looks up table `TableA` in database `DB_A` and sets data in `TableB` in database `DB_B` to match the contents of `TableA`, creating, updating or deleting data rows as needed.

Accessing both databases is done through a specific `ControllerDB` class from a custom `DAL` method library, that has methods `Select()`, `Insert()`, `Update()`, and `Delete()`. `ControllerDB` implements the interface `IControllerDB`.

Here is the simplified code:

**Main project**

```cs
public class BasicWorkingClass
{
    public IControllerDB ControllerDB_A { get; set; }

    public IControllerDB ControllerDB_B { get; set; }

    // Other IControllerDB properties, accessing other databases
}

public class MaintainDB_B : BasicWorkingClass
{
    public void MaintainTableB()
    {
         // Uses ControllerDB_A.Select() to list the contents of TableA in database DB_A

         // Then uses ControllerDB_B.Select() to loop through TableB from database DB_B

         // Using the contents of TableA and TableB, uses ControllerDB_B.Insert(),
         //  ControllerDB_B.Update() and ControllerDB_B.Delete() to make data in TableB
         //  match that in TableA
    }

    // Other methods maintain other tables in DB_B
}
```

**Testing project**

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class TestMaintainDB_B
{
    public MaintainDB_B MaintainDB_B_Instance;

    protected Mock<IControllerDB> MockControllerDB;

    protected List<ClassLikeTableA> ListTableA;

    [Setup]
    public void ResetStuffBeforeTesting()
    {
        MaintainDB_B_Instance = new MaintainDB_B();

        MockControllerDB = new Mock<IControllerDB>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMaintainTableB()
    {
        MockControllerDB.Setup(co => co.Select(It.IsAny<ClassLikeTableA>))
                        .Returns(ListTableA);
        // Four other Setup() calls mock Select, Insert, Update and Delete targeting TableB
        // It works with just one Mock<IControllerDB> object because all four methods have a
        //  parameter that indicates which table is targeted as seen above

        MaintainDB_B_Instance.ControllerDB_A = MockControllerDB.Object;
        MaintainDB_B_Instance.ControllerDB_B = MockControllerDB.Object;

        // Start testing proper
    }
}
```

Recently, a new person was added to the team, and convinced us that `BasicWorkingClass` having `IControllerDB` properties is a code smell because some classes that inherit from `BasicWorkingClass` have no use for `ControllerDB_A` and others have none for `ControllerDB_B`.

So we've been replacing those properties with `using (IControllerDB z_objLocalController = new ControllerDB())` blocks in the classes that needed corrections or evolutions.

Now `MaintainDB_B` needs corrections, so I've started replacing `ControllerDB_A` as mentioned.

The issue is, how do I keep mocking the database access?

1. Move every database access occurrence in its own `public` method, then mock each method. I understand that it's another code smell because those methods are supposed to be used only inside the class.
2. Create `IControllerDB` properties in `MaintainDB_B` and use them instead of those from `BasicWorkingClass`. I fear that it's another code smell too since, well, they aren't supposed to be `public` either.
3. Something else?

Comment: Can't you use some [CDC (change data capture)](https://www.qlik.com/us/change-data-capture/cdc-change-data-capture) tool to do this database replication job on your behalf?

Comment: @PeterCsala: That would be a possibility, yes, but right now the team has more pressing matters to address. Also, CDC is "perfect for modern cloud architectures" and our projects still use legacy databases.